# how to disable autocapitalization for specific words?

Tags: org-mode, capitalization, auto-capitalize-mode

I use org-mode, with auto-capitalize-mode turned on.

But sometimes, within org-mode, I want to type out some lisp, highlight it, and execute it.

I might type something like

`(setq org-cycle-emulate-tab)`

Auto-capitalize automatically capitalizes setq to Setq.

I don't feel like switching modes to emacs-lisp-mode or disabling auto-capitalize-mode. I just want it to recognize that I never want the word `setq` capitalized.

How can I disable autocapitalization for certain specific words?

Comment: Is it possible you have modified the library so that the default behavior no longer exists:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26590746/2112489

Comment: I think that modification is a list of words for which the NEXT word should not be capitalized, e.g. the word AFTER "e.g." should never be capitalized. But I want a list of words that should THEMSELVES never be capitalized.

Comment: Lines 61 to 63 of the comments in the source code -- https://github.com/yuutayamada/auto-capitalize-el/blob/master/auto-capitalize.el -- state:  "**To prevent a word from ever being capitalized or upcased (e.g. "http"), simply add it (in lowercase) to the `auto-capitalize-words' list.**"

Comment: So like this? `(setq auto-capitalize-words '("I" "setq"))`

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding based on a brief look at the source-code; however, I've never actually used that library -- so give it a try and see what happens.  If it doesn't work, consider temporarily removing your other customizations of that particular library to see if a conflict exists.  The comments in the source-code also discuss making exceptions in a particular context (if that feature interests you) and there is a guide of how to accomplish that goal.

Comment: It works. The other modification you refer to was to auto-capitalize-predicate, not auto-capitalize-words, which I had not customized.

Comment: I answered with eval-expression ( M-: ) but the OP said " another reason I often type setq in an org-mode environment is to change my config. I keep my Emacs config in org-mode files, inside source code blocks. I can do <kbd>C-c '</kbd> to enter the source code block, but sometimes I just want to quickly type in a setting without entering the block."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc-string for the variable `auto-capitalize-words` states as follows:  "*If non-nil, a list of proper nouns or acronyms.  If 'auto-capitalize' mode is on, these words will be automatically capitalized or upcased as listed (mixed case is allowable as well), even in the middle of a sentence.  **A lowercase word will not have its casemodified**.*"  [Admittedly, the comments in the source-code, *infra*, are more concise than the doc-string itself.]

Lines 61 to 63 of the source-code -- https://github.com/yuutayamada/auto-capitalize-el/blob/master/auto-capitalize.el -- contain comments that state:  "*To prevent a word from ever being capitalized or upcased (e.g. "http"), simply add it (in lowercase) to the 'auto-capitalize-words' list.*"

The original poster has confirmed (in the comments underneath the original question) that the following setting resolves his issue:

```
(setq auto-capitalize-words '("I" "setq"))
```

Comment: This works for lowercase words like `setq` but it doesn't respect mixed-case words like `iPhone`. How do I add the word "iPhone" to `auto-capitalize-words` so that auto-capitalize-mode respects its case?